# How to define an environment variable systemwide with /etc/environment?

Tags: administration, etc

I am trying to set an environment variable system wide.

Following the ubuntu site [recommendations](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide%20environment%20variables) , I set it up to my /etc/environment file.

The thing is when I log out and log in again, I have to source it if I want my environment variable to be set. What am I missing ?

Thank you,

Content :

```
MYVAR="/home/user/mypath"
```

Comment: Can you show the exact content of `/etc/environment` file? And I hope your logout/login sequence does not correspond to "close terminal / open terminal".

Comment: What I mean by logout/login is when I ssh myself to a server. I would like the varaible to stay set even when I leave the server.

Comment: Environment should stay for the ssh session and all of its childs, without the need to source /etc/environment. What do you mean by "when I leave the server"?

Comment: ~/.bashrc and ~./.bash_aliases is what your looking for in most cases. These files are read every time you run bash. If you are not using bash then you should have a look a what ever programming you are running and changing its environment at start up.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a variable like pythonpath like this `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/chris/my_new_path/` this concatenates the existing data of your variable with the new path.

You can check if your variable is set correctly with `echo $MY_VAR` and you can check your environment variables with the command `printenv` everything from a console.

You can add the export command to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` file in order not to execute it manually every time you log in.

Comment: The user ask for a "system wide" variable. Also, .bash-aliases, though it will work, is not conceptually the place to use.

Comment: Debian suggests a policy against wide system variables, there is a workaround to make things more elegant:

http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s9.9